# Windows 10: 0x80070241 - Download Error (Windows Update)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates, software-update, windows-insider

I've joined the Insiders and now i'm updating but, when i update, an error comes up stating its 0x80070241 error code... how can i fix this? this problem is going for a while now.

Here's a link to the pic:
[Download_Error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ljpf.png)

if someone takes effort in answering my question, i'd be delighted to thank you so much!

here's a link where you can find about the log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FlaZ6-6_kYseL85XVsqRw0T9txpVDn34/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is your machine on a domain, or connected to a WSUS server?

Comment: no it's not a domain and i don't know if its connected to the WSUS server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you with this problem.
At first, Run windows update troubleshooter. Just go to Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Update. Then, follow onscreen instructions. If you are not windows 10 user, You should find the update troubleshooter from control panel.
If first one doesn’t work, try to reset software distribution folder and then try to update windows.
In case, You still get the error code, you may consider to reset catroot2 folder.

Regards,

Comment: +1 thanks! but, i already done that things... like resetting windows update completely by resetting it's security properties... and more! and using the troubleshooter well, it reported that it's ok...

Comment: @RonTech you should state that in your question so we don't cover the same ground as you did.

Comment: I'm sorry :( ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then type `services.msc` and hit Enter.
2. Find and double-click on `Windows Update` and then click on `Stop`.
3. Delete the Windows Update cache, go to `%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\Download` and delete the contents.
4. Start the `Windows Update` service up again.
5. Try a Windows Update